# Странное поведение колонок bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap4

Имеется dropdown, при наведении на участок хедера с этим самым dropdown появляется белое простраство, как-будто элемент выше, чем на самом деле, уже все перепробовал все, что угодно, ничего не помогает...

```
export default class AboutPopup extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <>
          {/* <a href="/about">
            О нас&nbsp;&nbsp;<span></span>
          </a> */}
          <div id="about-modal">
            <div className="about-content">
              <div className="about-body">
                <div className="about-row">
                  <div className="about-item">
                    <img src={history} alt="icon" />
                    <div className="about-sub">
                      <div className="about-title">История компании</div>
                      <div className="about-subtitle">
                        Хронология значимых событий нашей компании
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="about-item">
                    <img src={stories} alt="icon" />
                    <div className="about-sub">
                      <div className="about-title">Истории успеха</div>
                      <div className="about-subtitle">
                        Кто о чем мечтал и что из этого получилось
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="about-row">
                  <div className="about-item">
                    <img src={managers} alt="icon" />
                    <div className="about-sub">
                      <div className="about-title">Топ-менеджмент</div>
                      <div className="about-subtitle">
                        Руководители о себе и о команде Smartech
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="about-item">
                    <img src={reviews} alt="icon" />
                    <div className="about-sub">
                      <div className="about-title">Отзывы</div>
                      <div className="about-subtitle">
                        Партнеры и клиенты о нас и сотрудничестве с нами
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button className="footer-button">
                  <img src={contacts} alt="icon" />
                  <p>Контакты</p>
                </button>
                <button className="footer-button">
                  <img src={write} alt="icon" />
                  <p>Напишите нам</p>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```

```
 #about-modal { 
   display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5000; 
    top: 26px;
    left: -220px;
    
  
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgba(204, 229, 253, 0);
  
    width: 545px;
    height: 242px;
    margin: .125rem 0 0;
    margin-top: 18px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: .25rem;
  }
  
  #about_search {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #about_search:hover {
    box-shadow: -4px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 30%);
  }
  
   #about-modal:hover {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
  } 
  
   #about_search:hover #about-modal {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
  } 
  
  .about-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    position: absolute;
  
  
  }
  
  .about-body {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  
  .about-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .about-item {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  
  
  .about-sub {
    padding-left: 15px;
    max-width: 210px;
  }
  
  .about-title {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
  }
  .about-title:hover {
    color: #00aeef;
  }
  
  .about-subtitle {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
  }
  
  .modal-footer {
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #00b5c9;
    padding: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-between !important;
    align-items: center !important;
  }
  .footer-button {
    width: 45%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #00b5c9;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
  }
  .footer-button:hover {
    background-color: #167885;
  }
  .footer-button img {
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
```